# How to open a .swf to view contents

Tags: flash

I want to get some images from a flash webpage and I got the .swf files. Is there a way to open the .swf and grab the contents of that file. I am not asking how to play the file or view the file. I actually want to open up the file and view its contents, if possible. I don't know anything about flash and tried searching already. It probably isn't possible since i didn't find any answers via search, but I wanted to try here first.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, it's perfectly possible, SWF is basically a zipped wrapper of assets and bytecode. Try one of these tools: http://www.swftools.org/

Comment: cool this works decently. thanks! I wasn't prepared to use the cmd line though. :D

Comment: I can't import SWF file. only PDF file

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to do this of which I can tell you 2:

1. SWF Decompiler - the most easy one
2. SWF Mill which works brilliant under linux and exports your images encoded in Base64

Comment: SWF decompiler used to work for me on my mac but sadly the current version is buggy and does not work at least not on mac 10.6.8 but there is flex decompiler but it is not free.

Answer (score 1):

Swf file is a kind of compiled binary file. If u wanna get its inside contents, u will decompile the file. This is not a regular way. Anyway, there are some tools can do this in  the internet.

Answer (score 1):

open the file with Adobe Flash CS6 Professional. Then you can convert it into a .FLA and view and edit it's content.  SWF files are made with this program so it should be able to open and edit the easily.

Comment: This is not the case. A swf must be decompiled before being opened in CS6 unless you have the source FLA, of course.

Answer (score -10):

Simply open with your browser (**Fire fox, Chrome**)

Comment: The OP said that they do not want to play or view the file, as they want to view the contents (i.e source code.)